# Laravel HasOne выдает ошибку "Undefined property"

Tags: laravel

Содержание функции в модели:

```
public function inShop()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Http\Models\Shop\User');
}
```

Обращаюсь в цикле вот так:

```
{{ var_dump($referral->inShop()->id) }}
```

Содержание ошибки:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$id
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть какие поля в таблицах ты завел.

Answer (score 0):

Точно ли у вас модель в этой папке App\Http\Models\Shop? Автоматом она создается просто в папке App. Либо имена ключевых полей не по правилам заданы.

Answer (score 0):

Обращаться к отношению надо так:

```
{{ var_dump($referral->inShop->id) }}
```

Пишите `..->inShop()->..`, если хотите добавить какое-нибудь условие.

См. [Laravel::Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)